# Obtaining OAuth2.0 access token for Facebook application

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have an application on Facebook with the API key, application secret etc....

I'm trying the use the Facebook API from a java application and it's telling me that it requires an OAuth2.0 access token. I tried googling about but I'm a bit lost. From where could I get this?

Thank a lot :)
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 1):

See:

**[Facebook Graph API — getting access tokens](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/)**